# How do you install cocos2d-iphone on the Mac?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

There are no good instructions for installing cocos2d for iPhone on the mac.

1. I downloaded the current build from git, a folder called "cocos2d-iphone-0.99.1". i put this folder in /Developer/Libary. Q: is this right?
2. I tried running the file called "install_template.sh". it said the templates were already installed.
3. Instead, I manually dragged the templates folders where they belong, and they ~do~ appear in the XCode's "New Project" dialog.
4. When I create a new cocos2d project, I see all these red links for project files, instead of the regular black links. When I try to open them in the finder, nothing happens.

I can tell that something is not linked. Can someone please help walk me through this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to just skip the bothersome parts and jump right into Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com). Kobold2D is still Cocos2D but it aims to remove all the annoying parts and get you started faster.

Answer (score 2):

To install the templates, these instructions worked for me.  You can see them [here](http://iphonedev.net/2009/07/28/how-to-install-cocos2d-08-project-template/). Otherwise you can just download the library and use it.  No install is really needed.

Comment: i had seen those instructions. i tried to follow them, but hit a snag on step 7:

"Step 7: Add Direct Dependency. After a new project is created, right click the target and select Get Info. Under General, click the ‘+’ button of Direct Dependencies."

However, when I select get info, the info window is empty and says "Nothing to inspect"... there is no "general" section or "+" button.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the cocos2d files to your project in Xcode.